# How to speed up the SQL query execution time in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

Below is my SQL query.

```
SELECT `left_table`.`right_table_id`, MAX(left_table.add_time) AS max_add_time 
    FROM `left_table` 
    LEFT JOIN `right_table` ON `left_table`.`right_table_id` = `right_table`.`id` 
    WHERE left_table.add_time <= NOW()
        AND (
                (right_table.some_id = 1 AND right_table.category != -2)
                OR
                (right_table.another_id = 1 AND right_table.category != -1)
        ) AND NOT(right_table.category = -3) 
        AND NOT(right_table.category = -4) 
    GROUP BY `right_table_id` 
    ORDER BY `max_add_time` DESC, `left_table`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 12
```

It takes `5356.6ms` to execute this query. It takes too long to me. I have been trying and trying to speed up the execution time. But no result. How can I improve the execution time for the above query?

Comment: Can you share explain plan?

Comment: Is `left_table.add_time` indexed? That would speed up the efficiency of the `MAX()` if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I would start by writing the logic like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT lt.`right_table_id`)
FROM `left_table` lt LEFT JOIN
     `right_table` rt
      ON lt.`right_table_id` = rt.`id` 
WHERE lt.add_time <= NOW() AND
      ((rt.some_id = 1 AND rt.category <> -2) OR
       (rt.another_id = 1 AND rt.category <> -1)
      ) AND
      rt.category NOT IN (-3, -4);
```

There might be additional simplifications, depending on whether `lt.right_table_id` always matches a row in the right table (or is `NULL`).  And various other considerations.

Comment: Dude, thanks for your answer. How about my SELECT query without COUNT() function. How can I speed it up. Because without the COUNT() function is the execution time also long.